# How to correct code so that It will run on all browsers

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, http

I have a server that I'm trying to get live information from and in FireFox it works fine and in every other browser the live data is not populating because of using xml. I understand that chrome and what not doesn't allow xml but I'm not sure how to fix this. Wondering if someone can lend their knowledge to help me out. Here is the code. I believe the issue is in the else if of the function loadXMLDoc based on what chrome says is the error---xmldoc.load is not a function.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">

// Object to load the live standings
    var xmldoc;
    function loadXMLDoc(xmlurl) {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  // code for IE
  xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmldoc.onreadystatechange = state_Change
  xmldoc.async = true
  xmldoc.load(xmlurl);
} else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
  // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
  xmldoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null)
  xmldoc.async = true
        xmldoc.onload = populate
  xmldoc.load(xmlurl)
} else {
  // alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
}
}
var interval, livetab

function populate() {
livetab = document.getElementById ? document.getElementById('livetable') :        document.all.livetable

// First remove all existing rows from the body
for (var i = livetab.tBodies[0].rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    livetab.tBodies[0].deleteRow(i)
}

// Load the rows
if (xmldoc != null) {

   var xn
 // Do the common data here
   xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('track')[0].childNodes[0]
 livetab.caption.innerHTML = (xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue)
   xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('server')[0].childNodes[0]
 document.getElementById('server').innerHTML = (xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue)
   xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('session')[0].childNodes[0]
 document.getElementById('session').innerHTML = (xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue)
   xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('progress')[0].childNodes[0]
 document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = (xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue)

   for ( var row = 0; row < xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('standings').length; row++) {
       // Add rows
       var r = livetab.tBodies[0].appendChild(document.createElement('tr'))
     r.className = 'detail' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
   var c

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col1' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('position')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col2' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('driver-name')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col3' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('vehicle')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col4' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('best-lap')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col5' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('behind-leader')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col6' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('last-lap-time')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col7' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('laps-led')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col8' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('total-laps')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)

     c = document.createElement('td')
     c.className = 'col12' + (row & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even')
     xn = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('finish-status')[row].childNodes[0]
     c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xn == null ? '' : xn.nodeValue))
     r.appendChild(c)
   }
  }

// Refresh interval
clearInterval(interval)
interval = setInterval("loadXMLDoc('ARCALive?id=livedata')", 6000)
}

window.onload = function() { loadXMLDoc('ARCALive?id=livedata') }
//window.onload = function() { loadXMLDoc('ARCALive/ARCATest.xml') }
</script>
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow XML? Since when? Unless something has changed, I'm not aware of that. Or the whatnots either.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was that Chrome doesn't allow the xml load method to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Not load()

and secondly the reason load is not a function is because you dont make a xml request as ActiveXObject doesn't exist in chrome(and some other modern browsers) you have to use XMLHttpRequest where you instead use document.implementation.createDocument which doesn't get the xml file but instead just creates a empty html/xml document

Edit: added example:

JS:

```
function getXML ( url ) {
  var xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');

  xmlReq.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if ( xmlReq.readyState == 4 && xmlReq.status == 200 )
    {
        createTable( xmlReq.responseXML );
    }
  };

  xmlReq.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlReq.send();
}

function createTable ( xmlDoc ) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tr;
  var c;

  //you should modify this to work with your xml
  for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
    c = xmlDoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[i];

    tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for (var I = 0; I < c.childNodes.length; I++) {
        tr.innerHTML += "<td>" + c.childNodes[I].innerHTML + "</td>";
    }

    table.appendChild(tr);

  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tabel>
    <row>
        <test>a</test>
        <test2>ab</test2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <test>b</test>
        <test2>bb</test2>
    </row>
</tabel>
```

so doing this:

```
getXML('test.xml');
```

would give you a table that looks somewhat like this:

```
a    ab
b    bb
```